# how to set custom error page for restricting access to sitefinity backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc, custom-error-pages

I use sitefinity cms ver 9.1 to manage my ASP.NET MVC application.

The application uses custom membership provider(normal user) and normal admin login(backend user) where normal user is restricted to access sitefinity backend.

As per my expectation when normal user tries to access backend, ~/sitefinity the user must be taken to custom error page as i have configured it below.

Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //subscribe to Bootstrapper.Initialized event
        Bootstrapper.Initialized += new EventHandler<Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs>(Bootstrapper_Initialized);
    }

    void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
        {
            //use UnauthorizedPageAccessEvent
            EventHub.Subscribe<IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent>(new Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Events.SitefinityEventHandler<IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent>(OnUnauthorizedAccess));
        }
    }

    void OnUnauthorizedAccess(IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent unauthorizedEvent)
    {
        var url = unauthorizedEvent.Page.Url.TrimStart('~');
        //for this specific page redirect to CustomerLoginPage
        if (unauthorizedEvent.Page.Title.Contains("needadminrights"))
            unauthorizedEvent.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound");
    }
```

But it fails to invoke OnUnauthorizedAccess() method when unauthorized user(normal user) tries to access the ~/sitefinity.
It throws this page.
[image: Default Error Page]

I followed the post below on sitefinity to implement custom Error page when user is unauthorized.
http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/stefani-tacheva-s-blog/2014/03/11/redirect-unauthorized-users-to-a-custom-page

i am not quite sure why this fails, Need help.

**EDIT 1** : According to Sitefinity, /Sitefinity is not an protected page. So it Fails to Invoke OnUnauthorizedAccess.

So, I tried custom error pages in application level in web.config.

Web.Config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <clear />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/NotFound">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

ErrorController:

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return View();
        }
```

It turns up to show 404 Custom Error View for all scenarios, like ~/csdklj/slfk.
But again fails to show 404 error for ~/Sitefinity.

It renders the same Error page with 404.15.

Comment: That error in particular is related to a very long query string - can you remove it for a bit and try? Also, make sure the /Error/NotFound page is accessible to Everyone to avoid recursion

Comment: Thanks for the response.NotFound view and Error controller is accessible to everyone. i am not sure why the lengthy query string is generated.

Comment: if a user does not have the "This user can access site backend" permission then he/she will get an error message when they go to /sitefinity.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev No it does not. It throws me 404.15